# addAttributeToFilter not working with final_price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, collection, sql, product-collection

When I try using the `addAttributeToFilter` to the `final_price`, the list it not returned. It gives an error instead. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /mnt/webdrive/foo.foo-web.net/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php`

However, when I use it with the normal `price`, it will work without any problems!
I've used both `addAttributeToSelect('final_price')` as well as `$collection->addFinalPrice()` but neither seem to fix the issue.

The array I'm using is as follows:

```
 2016-08-17T12:12:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
 (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [attribute] => final_price
             [from] => 50000.00
             [to] => 150000.00
         )
 )
```

It's being returned in a column in the query though. Is there no way to filter the collection based on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's being returned in a column in the query though. Is there no way to filter the collection based on that?

It's a column from the joined price index, but not an **attribute**. That means, you cannot use `addAttributeToFilter` because Magento will try to load an EAV attribute `final_price` which does not exist.

But you can add the condition to the query directly:

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('final_price BETWEEN ? AND ?', [50000, 150000]);
```

Comment: I've tried that. Unfortunately that makes it omit items that are completely out of stock since for them the index/final_price is NULL.

Comment: Hmm, in this case you could try to fall back to "price" and replace `'final_price'` with `IFNULL(final_price, price)`

Comment: That's what I did. But it did feel a little dirty, especially since it will ignore promotions. Hopefully the client will not care about that.

Answer (score 2):

Going off the top of my head here but I don't think final_price is an actual attribute but rather calculated on the fly with PHP. Check you database table `eav_attribute` for the existence of that attribute code.

Comment: It's being returned in a column in the query though. Is there no way to filter the collection based on that?